# a well defined map ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider a variety $V$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$, $I=I(V) \subset k[X_1, \cdots, X_n]=R$ ($k$ a field) and $P \in V$.  We define the following :
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^n) = \left\{ \left[ \frac{r}{s} \right] \mid r, s \in R, s(P) \neq 0 \right\}
\end{equation*}
and 
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{O}_P(V) = \left\{ \left[ \frac{\overline{r}}{\overline{s}} \right] \mid \overline{r}, \overline{s} \in R/I, \overline{s}(P) \neq 0 \right\}.
\end{equation*}
I would like to show that the following map :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
f& : &  \mathcal{O}_P(\mathbb{A}^n) & \longrightarrow & \mathcal{O}_P(V) \\
&& \left[ \frac{r}{s}\right] & \mapsto & \left[ \frac{f(r)}{f(s)}\right] & = & \left[ \frac{r + I}{s + I} \right].\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
is well defined. First I thought it was rather obvious by construction. But then I was wondering what tells me that I am not dividing by $0$ .... Is it really obvious or am I missing something important here ? Thanks for your help, I am definitely not an algebra expert !!

Comment: Recall: what does $P\in V$ mean? Dividing by zero means $s\in I$. Can this happen if $P\in V$ and $s(P)\not=0$?

Comment: That means V is the zero of a polynomial but since $s(P) \neq 0$  and $ P \in V $ that means I can't divide by 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to hint to in the comment is the following. Dividing by zero in $\tfrac{\overline{r}}{\overline{s}}$ means $\overline{s} = 0$ in $R/I$, or equivalently, $s\in I$; thus, this is what we want to exclude.

Now suppose $P\in V$ and $s(P)\not=0$. What is $I$?- It's the ideal of polynomials which vanish on all of $V$ and therefore, in particular, on $P$. I.e., $g(P) = 0$ for all $g\in I$. Consequently, if $s(P)\not=0$, then $s\not\in I$. Thus $\overline{s}\not=0$ in $R/I$.

Now to the well-definedness w.r.t. the equivalence relation. The equivalence relation behind $\left[\tfrac{r}{s}\right] = \left[\tfrac{r'}{s'}\right]$ in $R = k[X_1,X_2,\dots X_n]$ says that $rs' = r's$. Now the residue class map $R\to R/I$ (for any ideal) is a ring homomorphism. Hence if $rs' = r's$, then also $\overline{r}\overline{s'} = \overline{r'}\overline{s}$, from which $\left[\tfrac{\overline{r}}{\overline{s}}\right] = \left[\tfrac{\overline{r'}}{\overline{s'}}\right]$ follows.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear to me, thanks! Once you have excluded the case where you can't divide by zero, is the "well define" obvious. If I take let's say $[\frac{r}{s}]=[\frac{r'}{s'}]$, then will the equality remain true modulo I ?

Comment: I just remember why I didn't make this a comment instead an answer in the first place: because it answers only part of the question. I'm sorry—let me expand...

Comment: This whole business goes under the name *localisation (of rings)*, if you want to have a look at it. One important thing to note is that we're a little lucky here that the polynomial ring has no zero divisors...

Comment: so the equivalence relation is due to this localisation, right ? I'll check that up ! thanks again